# Unregistered values of rel attribute in anchor tag

Tags: html, anchor, rel, hashbang

I used rel values in jQuery for the parametrized (#!hashbang) AJAX calls.

```
<a id='_qualifier' rel='telephony' href='contact.php'>contact</a>
```

and with jQuery:

```
var hashbang = "#!"+$("#_qualifier").attr('rel'); //gives desired result=>"#!telephony"
```

But, when I validated the page on validator.w3.org, it gave me error:

> Bad value #telephony for attribute rel on element a: Keyword #telephony is not registered.

I searched around and according to the HTML5 specs [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes) and [here](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions), the rel attribute should have the registered/pre-defined values.

1. Is there a work around to use custom values for rel in HTML5, without failing the validation?
2. Is it also invalid for HTML4 doctypes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use custom attributes:

```
<a href="#" data-something="telephony">...</a>
```

It is HTML5 compliant, but not HTML4 or xHTML.
You'll access the attribute just like you did with jQuery.

You can find more informations on [the HTML5 reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is exactly what I need and what I was doing with rel attribute. The JavaScript/jQuery can access this attribute's value even in non-HTML5 compliant browsers. Hence it's fulfilling my purpose. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a work around to use custom values for rel in HTML5, without failing the validation?

The microformats page is a Wiki. If you are satisfied that you are using `rel` correctly and that there is no other appropriate rel value already registered, you can add you own value as a **Proposed** value. Instructions for doing so can be found here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/links.html#other-link-types

According to the HTML5 spec, this will make your rel value valid. Of course, it may take some time before automated validators catch up with this, but that's just a technical matter.

> Is it also invalid for HTML4 doctypes?

No, it isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guess identifying the right value for relationship between the current and target page within the same domain (or in my case) would be a stretch. I would go with @ldiqual's suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

You can use any other attribute of 'a' tag for eg. 'title'

Comment: Attributes have their own meanings and effects; for example, the `title` attribute value typically appears as a tooltip on mouseover.